# Correct Way to Register for SCREEN_OFF and SCREEN_ON events

Tags: android

So I recently discovered that `SCREEN_OFF` and `SCREEN_ON` actions can't be received by registering them in an application's manifest (no idea why), which requires me to register programmatically instead.

However, I'm not sure where would be the best place to do this? Ideally I would like to just register by `BroadcastReceiver` to handle these events just like I handle everything else, but where should I actually perform the registration? Is there another action I could register to that would be a better place for me to perform such setup actions?

Currently I'm doing this by triggering a broadcast in the main activity when opened, that the receiver can then receive, and attempt to register itself for screen events. But this will only work if the application has been run at least once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register a `BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver and use that to run the code that would listen to screen off/on should the device get rebooted.

Note you will need the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission.

Comment: That seems easy enough, but what about detecting when a user first installs the app? When developing the app opens straight away once loaded onto a device, but when you download from the Google Play store that doesn't happen, is it possible to detect installation?

Comment: You can't expect your code to run without the user explicitly starting it at least once. There are obvious security implications if that was possible.